# The multi-part identifier could not be found via convert query

Tags: sql, sql-convert

```
 select convert(date, Main_Users_ActivityLog.CreateDate);
```

I'm having trouble working on this query. How can I convert all contributions from a column to the type I wish to use, only a line of code?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? SQL is just the query language - but it often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: ok i will take your advice next time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `FROM` clause:

```
select convert(date, Main_Users_ActivityLog.CreateDate)
FROM Main_Users_ActivityLog;
```

Comment: oh yes i forgot :D